# How should I cite the "Short Math Guide for LaTeX"?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

For purposes of creating a BibTeX entry for the 2017 edition of the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX, version 2.0](http://tug.ctan.org/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf) by Downes and Beeton, what type of document is it? Is it a report, a book, a manuscript, misc, or something else? An [entry in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22short+math+guide%22+latex+downes+2002&btnG=) for a previous version of the guide lists it as a book, which seems incorrect for such a short document.  OTOH, it lacks a report number, so maybe isn't a report either.

Comment: How about `booklet`?

Comment: To some degree the 'best' input also depends on what you want to get out and on the style you (intend to) use. From the standard BibTeX styles I would seriously consider `@manual`, although the already mentioned `@booklet` could also work. `@unpublished` and `@misc` are always worth a try as a fallback type. If you use `biblatex`, you could additionally look into `@online`.

Comment: I too would be reluctant to go for `@techreport`, because there is no report series and number. And even though `@book` might not feel quite right, it could work as well.

Answer (score 5):

A quick experiment:

[image]

`a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Book~\cite{downes2017short}.
Booklet~\cite{downes2017short-booklet}.
Manual~\cite{downes2017short-manual}.
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{a}
\end{document}
```

`a.bib`:

```
@book{downes2017short,
  title =    {Short math guide for {\LaTeX}},
  author =   {Downes, Michael},
  year =     2017,
  edition =  {second},
  publisher =    {American Mathematical Society},
}

@booklet{downes2017short-booklet,
  title =    {Short math guide for {\LaTeX}},
  author =   {Downes, Michael},
  year =     2017,
  note =     {Second edition},
  howpublished = {American Mathematical Society},
}

@manual{downes2017short-manual,
  title =    {Short math guide for {\LaTeX}},
  author =   {Downes, Michael},
  year =     2017,
  edition =  {second},
  organization = {American Mathematical Society},
}
```

Comment: `@manual`s have `organization` as functional equivalent of `@book`'s `publisher`. `@booklet` has no such thing, but one could use `howpublished`. (I'm referring here to the BibTeX base styles as documented in http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf, of course things can be different with other styles.)

Comment: @moewe, cool. My answer was modified to reflect your comments.